# Can't search data in prisma schema using aonther shcema in nestjs

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, backend, prisma

EDIT:

Use where: { id: userId } `don't help` beacuse it search using the id of the bookmark and not by the user who added the bookmark

My goal is to be able to search in the bookmarks table using userId from another model.

In this model file using Prisma, i have two models (one for users and one for bookmarks):

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  email String @unique
  hash  String

  firstName String?
  lastName  String?

  bookmarks Bookmark[]

  @@map("users")
}

model Bookmark {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  title       String
  description String?
  link        String

  userId Int
  user   User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])

  @@map("bookmarks")
}
```

To create the seacrh using userId , I using nestjs service that run this function :

```
getBookmarksByUserId(userId: number) {
    return this.prisma.bookmark.findMany({
        where: {
            userId: userId
        }
    });
}
```

But when I run my test an error pop up:

```
Unknown arg `userId` in where.userId for type BookmarkWhereInput. Did you mean `id`? Available args:
type BookmarkWhereInput {
  AND?: BookmarkWhereInput | List<BookmarkWhereInput>
  OR?: List<BookmarkWhereInput>
  NOT?: BookmarkWhereInput | List<BookmarkWhereInput>
  id?: IntFilter | Int
  createdAt?: DateTimeFilter | DateTime
  updatedAt?: DateTimeFilter | DateTime
  title?: StringFilter | String
  description?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null
  link?: StringFilter | String
}
```

And i tried everything, use AND , use equle, use include but no success.

what i missing ?

Comment: Use `where: { id: userId }`. `userId` is not a valid column in the `User` table/schema

Comment: But i need to search using the user id in the bookmark model, the { id: } param ref to the if of the bookmark

Comment: Did you recreate prisma after chaniging prisma? `npx prisma generate`

Answer (score 0):

after changing prisma schema you should generate  with this command `npx prisma generate`
if you already did it

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

async function getUserBookmarks(userId: number) {
  const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: { id: userId },
    include: { bookmarks: true },
  });

  return user?.bookmarks;
}
```

you can use that to get bookmarks together with user
2 solution is getting bookmark straight in bookmark table

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

async function getUserBookmarks(userId: number) {
  const bookmarks = await prisma.bookmark.findMany({
    where: { user: { id: userId } },
  });

  return bookmarks;
}
```

prisma creates imaginary fields for self when you join tables like user field and you can use that for joining and searching things